# is there a way to fix katex from overflowing?

Tags: css, react-native, katex

I am currently trying to solve katex equations from overflowing in react native webview. I am trying to break the equations dynamically into multiple lines, such that it does not scroll and will come in separate lines. Any help will be appreciated very much.

Comment: Can you provide some code and screenshots?

Comment: i can't share the code, as it is to big to put it here, you can refer to this https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/issues/327

Answer (score 0):

KaTeX supports automatic line breaking after binary relations and operators, but *only in inline math* as created by `$...$` or `\(...\)`.  See [this documentation](https://katex.org/docs/supported.html#line-breaks). So if you can switch from display mode (which doesn't do automatic line breaking) to inline mode, you should get the desired behavior.

If you want to use display equations (e.g. you want the equations centered), [this recently added CSS customization help](https://katex.org/docs/issues.html#css-customization) specifies how to allow line breaks in display equations.